# Getting description like NSObject

Tags: swift, debug-symbols, println

If you run the following in Playgroud

```
class Test {
  var description:String {
    return "This is Test"
  }
}

class Test1:NSObject {
  override var description:String {
    return "This is Test"
  }
}

let t = Test()
println(t)
let t1 = Test1()
println(t1)
```

you see that the first `println` will output some debugger blurb while the second echoes the contents of `description`.

So: is there a way that "normal" classes will be treated the same way as subclasses of `NSObject` so `println` will respect the contents of a `description` property?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `println()` API documentation:

```
/// Writes the textual representation of `object` and a newline character into
/// the standard output.
///
/// The textual representation is obtained from the `object` using its protocol
/// conformances, in the following order of preference: `Streamable`,
/// `Printable`, `DebugPrintable`.
///
/// Do not overload this function for your type.  Instead, adopt one of the
/// protocols mentioned above.
func println<T>(object: T)
```

So in order to get a custom `println()` representation, your class must (e.g.) adopt the `Printable` protocol explicitly:

```
class Test : Printable {
    var description:String {
        return "This is Test"
    }
}
```

However, this does not work in a Playground of Xcode 6.1.1.
It has been fixed in Xcode 6.3 beta. From the release notes:

> • Adding conformances within a Playground now works as expected, ...

I could not find this in the API headers, but it seems that `NSObject`
(and its subclasses) are already known to conform to `Printable`.
Therefore the custom description works for your `Test1` class.

---

In **Swift 2 (Xcode 7),** the `Printable` protocol has been renamed
to `CustomStringConvertible`:

```
class Test : CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description:String {
        return "This is Test"
    }
}

let t = Test()
print(t)
// This is Test
```

Comment: You just know it all :-)

Comment: In swift 2.0, 'Printable' has been renamed to 'CustomStringConvertible'.

Comment: Also in Swift 3.0 (maybe earlier as well) description needs to be public.

Comment: @Warpzit: That's *necessary* if the class itself is declared public (e.g. in a framework), not if the class is defined locally (e.g. in the app). But it won't do any harm to add the public modifier in any case, so I have added it to avoid any confusion. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are printing out an instance of  class. In swift, a class is not a default subclass of `NSObject` . To make a class a subClass of `NSObject` you have to specify it like you have done for the second class. Here's the modified code :

```
class Test {
  var description:String {
    return "This is Test"
  }
}

class Test1:NSObject {
  override var description:String {
    return "This is Test"
  }
}

let t = Test()
println(t.description)
let t1 = Test1()
println(t1)
```

Here's a quote from [*The Swift Programming Language*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html),

> Swift classes do not inherit from a universal base class. Classes you
>   define without specifying a superclass automatically become base
>   classes for you to build upon.

Comment: I know that I can use `t.desciption`. But how does `NSObject` manage that print takes its `description` property while it will not take it from normal classes? I guess it's some hidden foo Apple is doing under the hood.

Comment: - Just saw Martin's answer. Anyway I'll upvote yours for the effort you took :-)

Comment: Alright. Maybe I had mis-understood the question. I thought that you wanted to know the simplest way to avoid the error. Anyway, Good luck :)